# 5080 : Form transaction registration failed

Tags: transactions, gravity-forms-plugin, opayo

When checking out I get `5080 : Form transaction registration failed`.

[SagePay 5080 : Form transaction registration failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOF1R.png)

This happens every single time.  The SagePay online console shows these 5080 transactions as timing out after 15 minutes.  It provides no other useful information about the error.

An example of a failing pre-encrypted payload is:

```
VendorData=
&ReferrerID=CC923B06-40D5-4713-85C1-700D690550BF
&Amount=75
&CustomerName=
&CustomerEMail=example@test.co.uk
&BillingSurname=
&BillingFirstnames=
&BillingAddress1=My Flat,
&BillingAddress2=Example Road
&BillingCity=London
&BillingState=
&BillingPostCode=SW1 7DD
&BillingCountry=GB
&BillingPhone=01234567890
&DeliverySurname=
&DeliveryFirstnames=
&DeliveryAddress1=My Flat,
&DeliveryAddress2=Example Road
&DeliveryCity=London
&DeliveryState=
&DeliveryPostCode=SW1 7DD
&DeliveryCountry=GB
&DeliveryPhone=01234567890
&FailureURL=https://www.testing.co.uk/abc-road/?page=gf_sagepay_form_ipn
&SuccessURL=https://www.testing.co.uk/abc-road/?page=gf_sagepay_form_ipn
&Description=Order #71
&Currency=GBP
&VendorTxCode=71-0efe22606075c0e94d4399ad748df389
&VendorEMail=admin@test.com
&SendEMail=1
&Apply3DSecure=1
```

The checkout uses SagePay Form Gateway for Gravity Forms v1.2.1, Gravity Forms 2.1.2 and Wordpress 4.7.1.  Another form using the same plugin versions and configuration is able to checkout successfully.

Any ideas what's wrong with this particular submission?

Answer (score 0):

Missing Billing / Delivery first and surnames jump right out!

Also - try logging into My Sage Pay, clicking Transactions and then Invalid - the entry there should give you a more informative error message.